# update view immediately on datachanged

Tags: python, pyqt, signals

I have a table with cells like Excel. I know I need to emit `dataChanged` signal from my Model in order to update my View, it works perfectly. However, when the update comes from another (python) thread, I need to set my mouse (click once) on the updated cell in order the new value to be shown. I know the new value *is* correctly set in the Model (i can see the log), but the View is lagged behind..

If the update relates to the cell which is already active, the update is reflected immediatly.

What signal should I emit in order to force View to be updated without me clicking on the right cell?

**EDIT** It works now. I need to implement QThread rather than plain pythhon thread and to connect the signal to a handler from data model. Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning `QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'` was preventing `dataChanged` signal from being captured. This happened because this signal was emitted from another (pythonic) thread. In order to make it work, I needed to subclass QThead like:

```
class MyThread(QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            result= do stuff...
            self.updated.emit(result)
```

And in my `QAbstractTableModel`, connect the signal to my model:

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, rowCount: int, colCount: int, parent=None):
        super(QAbstractTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._listenerth = MyThread()
        self._listenerth.updated.connect(self.remote_update_handler)
        self._listenerth.start(QThread.LowPriority)

    def remote_update_handler(self,result):
        self.setData(QModelIndex,result, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
```

This made the warning gone, and update worked flawlessly